# Running a command line tool based on its extension

Tags: software, finder, filesystem

I use [Leo](http://webpages.charter.net/edreamleo/front.html) for structured editing of my code, and Leo has the extension of .leo.

In order to run Leo, I use the following alias

```
alias leo='arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6 /Users/bin/Leo-4.7.1-final/launchLeo.py --gui=qt'
```

It works well to launch leo with leo file as follows.

```
leo -f hello.leo
```

However, I need to find a way to launch Leo by clicking the leo file in the Finder/Path Finder.

What might be the solution to this problem?

### ADDED

Mankoff's advice on using Automator works.
For running PyQt with -f option, I set "Pass input : as argument", and have the following bash code, which launches with/without -f option depending a file is dragged on or not.

```
if [ -z $1 ]
then
  arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6 /Users/smcho/smcho/bin/Leo-4.8-b1/launchLeo.py --gui=qt 
else
  arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6 /Users/smcho/smcho/bin/Leo-4.8-b1/launchLeo.py --gui=qt -f $1
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Automator. Make an app that takes an argument (file dropped on it, file double-clicked associated with that app, whatever), and runs the command you have above.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on a .leo file and select Get Info
- On the [whatever.leo] info pane that opens, use the Open With drop-down to browse to the Leo editor.
- Click the Change All... button

Double clicking any .leo file should invoke the Leo editor from now on.